# Tomar datos para busqueda

Tags: php, sql

Buenas tardes, requiero de su sapiencia, necesito crear una búsqueda de valores (patente,año,tipo) de un vehículo, pero ademas de necesitar para esta búsqueda datos del usuario. Como se puede realizar esta situación. De antemano muchas gracias

```
  TABLE `clientes` (  
  `id_cliente` int(10)   
  `asegurado` varchar(80) NOT NULL     
  `rut` int(10) NOT NULL  
  `dv_rut` int(1) NOT NULL
  `direccion_comercial` varchar(100) NOT NULL  
  `telefono_uno` int(10) NOT NULL  
  `telefono_dos` int(10) NOT NULL  
  `email_cliente` varchar(70) NOT NULL  
  `persona_contacto` varchar(50) NOT NULL  
  `inspector` varchar(50) NOT NULL  
  `corredor` varchar(50) NOT NULL  
  `giro_actividad` varchar(30) NOT NULL  
  `jornada_laboral` int(1) NOT NULL,  
  `tiempo_negocio` int(4) NOT NULL,  
  `tiempo_ubicacion` int(4) NOT NULL,  
  `num_empleados` int(8) NOT NULL,  
  `relacion_laboral` varchar(25) NOT NULL  
  `otras_ubicaciones` varchar(80) NOT NULL  
  `id_cia` int(11) NOT NULL  
) 

     TABLE `inspeccion` (  
  `id_inspeccion` int(10) NOT NULL,  
  `num_solicitud` varchar(20) NOT NULL,  
  `num_propuesta` int(5) NOT NULL,  
  `direccion_riesgo` varchar(100)   
  `cod_region` int(2) NOT NULL,  
  `cod_provincia` int(3) NOT NULL,  
  `cod_comuna` int(4) NOT NULL,  
  `cod_localidad` int(5) NOT NULL,  
  `id_cliente` int(10) NOT NULL,  
  `tipo_siniestros` int(1) NOT NULL,  
  `tipo_moneda` int(1) NOT NULL,  
  `pardi_pxp` int(3) NOT NULL,  
  `perdi_pxp_porcentaje` int(3) NOT NULL,  
  `perdi_pxp_moneda` int(1) NOT NULL,  
  `fecha_solicitud` date NOT NULL,  
  `fecha_visita` date NOT NULL,  
  `fecha_coordinada` date NOT NULL,  
  `fecha_reinspeccion` date NOT NULL,  
  `num_personas` int(4) NOT NULL,  
  `tipo_prog_mantencion` int(1) NOT NULL,  
  `asesora_externa` varchar(80)   
  `stock_repuesto` varchar(100)  
  `estado_conservacion` int(1) NOT NULL,  
  `planes_contingencia` varchar(80) NOT NULL,  
  `instalacion_electronica` int(1) NOT NULL,  
  `protodo_trabajador` varchar(200) NOT NULL,  
  `id_cia` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `estado` varchar(15)  NOT NULL  
)
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola, vas a tener que agregar muchos mas datos para que podamos contestarte. Que probaste hasta ahora, como es tu formulario de entrada, que base de datos usas.